# Replace negative numbers with zero?

Tags: sed, awk

I have columns like this:

```
-0.000000650100  
0.000015560000  
-0.000003653000  
-0.000004339000  
0.000003259000
```

Need them to look like this:

```
0  
0.000015560000  
0  
0   
0.000003259000
```

Not having success with awk, suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
awk '{print($0<0?0:$0)}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/^-.*/0/' file
0
0.000015560000
0
0
0.000003259000
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '/^-/{$0=0}1' file
0
0.000015560000
0
0
0.000003259000
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use an if like the following pseudo-code:

```
if(getfirstchar($val)=="-"); then
$val = 0
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

if you enjoy obfuscated code without any numbers whatsoever, one could syntactically modify "Chris Seymour"'s solution into

```
mawk2 '/^\-/ {$_=+_} _^_'
```

or even

```
gawk '/^\-/ {$("")=""^""}!""'
```

but retaininig same functionality of it.